# LinkedIn Oauth scope issue with PHP library

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

I have been trying to implement the new scope features that were recently added to the LinkedIn API. I am currently using the "simple-linkedinphp" library for as my LinkedIn oauth lib (http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/ ).

Following the directions on the LinkedIn docs, I added the "scope" param to my request token URL as such:

```
  const _URL_REQUEST    = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress';
```

However, this had little effect. I still get the same o-auth dialogue as before without any additional permissions for the e-mail address. Anyone get this working correctly in PHP yet? Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the false answer, last time I used Linkedin API you couldnt get email address, anyway have you checked that the email address is returned when you try and get it?

Comment: It doesn't return it when I request it... and the o-auth dialogue I get doesn't look look like the o_auth dialogue I am supposed to get according to their docs. I still get the old o-auth dialogue without any extended permissoins on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [create new Application API keys](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/making-it-easier-you-develop-linkedin) and use those to see the updated authentication screens.

Comment: Ugh, that was totally it. I feel pretty dumb... that's what I get for not reading the press release in full :/