# Simple LinkedIn API tutorial for PHP

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I find the LinkedIn API Documentation for PHP horrible. Can anyone tell me how to [fetch company information](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields)? From authentication till the end response?

I'm a novice programmer, but I have successfully been able to use the Facebook and Twitter APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [PHP library](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/) with [demos](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/source/browse/trunk/v3/3.2/3.2.0/demo/company.php) that cover working with the [Company API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/companies). It's a little out of date, with regards to the new scoped permissions scheme that LinkedIn uses, but there are [workarounds to support the permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976188/linkedin-oauth-scope-issue-with-php-library).